# Inject constant to other modules config using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, constants

I would like to share some variables like base paths throughout my application.
These variables needs to be accessible during module configuration.
My opinion was, that I can use a constant or provider for that.

I've got several modules and each one has it's own routing configuration. In these routing configurations, I want to access some settings for example.

This is working for the app-module-configuration but not for other module-configurations (for controllers on other modules it does), I always get "Unknown provider: info from myApp.orders".

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.orders']);

myApp.constant('info', {
  version : '1.0'
});

myApp.config(function(info) {
  console.log('app config: ' + info.version);
});

myApp.controller('MyController', function (info) {
  console.log('controller: ' + info.version);
});

var orders = angular.module('myApp.orders', []);

// Remove comments to see it fail.

//orders.config(function(info) {
//  console.log('orders config: ' + info.version);
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div ng-app="myApp" class="container" ng-controller="MyController">        
  </div>
```

I guess I have just missed out a little detail, do you have an idea?

Comment: It seems while `orders.constant(...)` does not work, `orders.controller('ordersCtrl', function(info) {
      console.log('orders ctrl: ' + info.version);
    });` will (if you load the controller somewhere. Perhaps this helps.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your `info` constant is defined in your `myApp` module. If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to use the constants in other modules (e.g. myApp.orders module). If so, then you need to inject myApp into myApp.orders, but it looks like you want to do the reverse. One solution is to decouple the constants into a standalone module, and inject it as a dependency where needed.

```
angular.module('constants', []) 
  .constant(...);

angular.module('myApp', ['constants', 'myApp.orders'])
  ...

angular.module('myApp.orders', ['constants'])
  ...
```

Comment: that's working, thx and +1. I wonder why the constant injection work on a controller defined on module `myApp.orders` without injecting `myApp` into `myApp.orders` but not for the configuration of module `myApp.orders`, see here http://codepen.io/martinoss/pen/azVrew/

Comment: I believe I found the answer to my question in the comment on the offical site: _Modules can list other modules as their dependencies. Depending on a module implies that the required module needs to be loaded before the requiring module is loaded. In other words the configuration blocks of the required modules execute before the configuration blocks of the requiring module. The same is true for the run blocks. Each module can only be loaded once, even if multiple other modules require it._

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if my solution is the most pretty, but I put in my index.html a definition of a CONFIG that I reference from other components.  I generate my index.html with server side code so I can set the values when the program starts.  That is, I use index.cshtml but it just as easily be index.php or other technology.  Here is what my index.html looks like:

```
....

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var usingMockDataGlobal = true;
 </script>

....


<script type="text/javascript">

        (function () {
            'use strict';

            var configData = {


                codeCampType: 'angu',

                loggedInUsername: 'peter',
                mockData: usingMockDataGlobal
            };
            angular.module('baseApp').constant('CONFIG', configData);


        })();
    </script>
```