# AngularJS: Constants vs Values

Tags: angularjs

As far as I understand the documentation, the only concrete difference between a Constant and a Value is that a Constant can be used during the apps config phase, whereas a Value is only available during the run phase.

I am curious as to why Values are needed at all in this case? Aren't they really just limited Constants?

Comment: great tutorial http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/constants-values-global-variables-in-angularjs-the-right-way/

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A constant can be **injected anywhere**.

A constant can not be intercepted by a decorator, **that means that the value of a constant should never be changed**.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.constant('PI', 3.14159265359);

app.config(function(PI){
    var radius = 4;
    //PI can be injected here in the config block
    var perimeter = 2 * PI * radius;
});

app.controller('appCtrl', function(PI) {
    var radius = 4;
    // calculate area of the circle
    var area = PI * radius * radius; 
});
```

Value differs from constant in that value **can not be injected into configurations**, **but it can be intercepted by decorators**.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.value('greeting', 'Hello');

app.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('greeting', function ($delegate) {
        return $delegate + ' World!';
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like the language is the same as this gist. https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099 The code examples here are better, and illustrate the language. I'll propose an edit which adds an example of the language "a constant  can be injected anywhere" -- and implied by "a value cannot be injected into configurations", by showing the constant used in the app.config, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28416054/1175496)

Comment: What does it mean that value "can not be injected into configurations"? any example?

Comment: @VasylGutnyk it means, that *values* are not available during *configuration phase* and you can't inject it to `app.config` function

Comment: @Artem Petrosian, ok understad now, just start my angular road, and its all looks a little bit confusing:) thank u for answer.

Answer (score 7):

The difference between **value** and **constant** is that a value specified using constant is available during the configuration phase.

Well it’s the same for **value** and **constant**. **constant** is available from the configuration phase and **value** is not.

The other difference is as the name implies you can’t change the value of a constant. The first value you assign it is the value it keeps, if you try to assign it a different value later it will be ignored.

Here’s an example:

```
mod.value("myValue", "First Assignment");

mod.value("myValue", "Second  Assignment");

mod.constant("myConstant", "First Assignment");

mod.constant("myConstant", "Second Assignment");

mod.controller("MyController", function(myValue, myConstant) {

    console.log("myValue: " + myValue);

    console.log("myConstant: " + myConstant);
});
```

**Console output:**

```
myValue: Second Assignment

myConstant: First Assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

True, however, keep in mind if you use an object as a constant, its value can be overridden anytime, anywhere. For example

```
const version = '10.0'
```

can not be changed, if you take a look at the console it even throws an error when changing its value, but

```
const config = {
    'version': '8.6'
}
```

behaves like a simple value, you can change the the object values anytime, like this:

```
config.version = 5
```

tada, now your version is `5`.
Same applies for `app.const('constant', 'its me')`

Comment: I think you are talking about pure javascript. The question was referring to ```constants``` in AngularJS, which is not the same as ```const``` in javascript