# AngularJs set a global

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set a global for my entire app. But it's not working. Here I declare my globals:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('employeeApp')
        .controller('authenticationController', authenticationController)
        .constant('GLOBALS', {
            url:'http://skindustries.dev/api/v1/',
            role:'',
            companyid:'',
            name:''
        });
```

Then when a employee signs in I want to set globals.

```
function authenticationController(requestFactory,authenticationFactory,GLOBALS,$location,$cookieStore)
    {
    var vm = this;

        vm.login = function() {
            data = {"email": vm.email, "password": vm.password};
            requestFactory.post(GLOBALS.url + 'login', data)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    GLOBALS.role = response.data.result.Employee.Role;
                    GLOBALS.companyid = response.data.result.Employee.CompanyId;
                    authenticationFactory.setToken(response.data.result.Employee.api_token);
                    $cookieStore.put('employeeid', response.data.result.Employee.EmployeeId);
                    $location.path('/home');

                }, function () {
                    console.log('Niet ingelogd!');
                });
            }
        }
```

If I `console.log(GLOBALS.role)` in `authenticationController` result is `superadministrator`. Then the user is redirected to home. If I `console.log(GLOBALS.role)`  in my `homeController`.

```
(function()
{
    angular.module('employeeApp').controller('homeController', homeController);

    function homeController(employeeFactory,GLOBALS) {
        console.log(GLOBALS.role);
```

Result is `null`?

What am I doing wrong here!?

--EDIT--

**constant (service)**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('employeeApp')
        .service('constants',constants);

    function constants() {
        this.url = 'http://skindustries.dev/api/v1/';
            this.role =  'oldRole',
            this.companyid = '',
            this.name = ''
    }
})();
```

**login (factory)**

```
factory.login = function(email,password)
        {
            console.log('login');
            data = {"email": email, "password": password};
            requestFactory.post(GLOBALS.url + 'login', data)
                .then(function (response) {
                    constants.role = response.data.result.Employee.Role;
                    constants.companyid = response.data.result.Employee.CompanyId;
                    factory.setToken(response.data.result.Employee.api_token);
                    $cookieStore.put('employeeid', response.data.result.Employee.EmployeeId);
                    $location.path('/home');

                }, function () {
                    console.log('Niet ingelogd!');
                });
        }
```

**homeController**

```
(function()
{
    angular.module('employeeApp').controller('homeController', homeController);

    function homeController(constants) {
  console.log(constants.role);
}
```

Comment: did you cross-check that `GLOBALS` is being registered as angular  constant "before" 'homeController' gets executed ?

Comment: Yes I've checked that!

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at this blog post which deals with auth : http://www.jvandemo.com/learn-how-to-make-authentication-in-your-angular-applications-simpler-and-more-consistent/

Comment: @Deblaton would it be wrong to store this in a cookie?

Comment: @jamie Yes. A cookie is sent with every request the web client makes to the web server. If you need those information on your server, you should use JWT (JWT can be stored in a cookie, but I prefer dealing with it inside headers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically value (or a constant) initializes every time when it is injected in a controller. So it never retain your new value and hence initializes its old value.

For your need you could use a `service` as a global object in your application so that it retains your new saved value in the `GLOBAL` object

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/Lvc0u55v/1595/)

```
.service('GLOBALS', function() {
      this.url = 'http://skindustries.dev/api/v1/';
      this.role =  'oldRole',
      this.companyid = '',
      this.name = ''
  })

.controller('MyController', function(GLOBALS, $scope) {
  console.log(GLOBALS.role);
  $scope.role = GLOBALS.role;
  GLOBALS.role = "new role";
  console.log(GLOBALS.role);
})

.controller('MyController2', function(GLOBALS, $scope) {
  console.log(GLOBALS.role);
  $scope.role = GLOBALS.role;
});
```

For a better understanding of constants and values refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327651/angularjs-constants-vs-values)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this and reload the page the role is gone. Please see my edit.

Comment: Obviously @jamie the edited role will be gone because it is not saved in the session or an external DataBase. If you want your changed GLOBAL values to be saved you should use localStorage (that is browser specific) or a database to save your data.

Comment: No. It wouldn't be wrong, but the cookie will only be accessible inside that particular browser, just like localStorage. For example If you are hosting your application in chrome and edit data there it will only be accessible inside that browser and only by you. It would not be available on another browser say firefox.

Comment: Thanksyou! but now I've got another problem -_-

Comment: Yes you can ask it. Here to help. :)

Answer (score -1):

A constant can not be intercepted by a decorator, that means that the value of a constant should never be changed.

Use Value :

```
angular.module('app', []);

.value('GLOBALS', 'The Matrix');

.controller('MyController', function (GLOBALS) {
  GLOBALS = "hello";
})
```